# match the 1st field then join the line

Tags: awk, gawk

i have two files..
file1::

```
Adezat
Adm157
Adriaan
```

file2::

```
adezat:0f94154bdef31844e7c5e8aaaaaaaaaa:0X!SV
imawesome3:3c84a21b44f49163aa4597aaaaaaaaaa:5VMQX
adm157:1e00152082f4d02af24b16aaaaaaaaaa:@0E2F
imawesome:acdf80e6488ea6154ed9182aaaaaaaaaa:KJP6E
adriaan:74b57d1e76a16637cfa47faaaaaaaaaa:FVW&C
```

after matching the first field from both files >> print only the matched lines from file2::

```
adezat:0f94154bdef31844e7c5e8aaaaaaaaaa:0X!SV
adm157:1e00152082f4d02af24b16aaaaaaaaaa:@0E2F
adriaan:74b57d1e76a16637cfa47faaaaaaaaaa:FVW&C
```

note im using gawk with windows.. thanks

**[i got the answer](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/183299-joining-lines-only-if-1st-field-matches.html)**::

```
gawk -F":" "NR==FNR{a[tolower($1)]++;next}tolower($1) in a" file1 file2
```

Comment: Hmmm I wonder what files these are... Hmmm...

Comment: For educational purposes, I suppose?

Comment: could be but i dont think so...

Comment: Are both files sorted? Also, `adriaan` line is in output but not in `file1`.

Comment: @sarnold:: my bad.. no there are not sorted file2 is huge

Answer (score 1):

Using grep:

```
grep -i -f file1 file2
```

Answer (score 0):

not at a terminal at the moment, but:

```
join -t: <(tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' < file1 | sort) <(sort file2) | cut -d: -f 2-
```

but grep would be better